# Unable to load json data as strings inside it are in unicode

Tags: python, json

I have the following json string :

```
{u'debug': {u'version': 3.1}, u'status': u'OK', u'results': {u'api_timestamp': u'1439552208', u'totalCommentsFound': 9300, u'totalCommentsReturned': 25, u'comments': [{u'assetID': 3425398, u'replies': [], u'lft': 9, u'assetURL': u'http://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/03/31/why-i-moved-to-florida/', u'parentID': 14580714, u'commentID': 14581040, u'rgt': 10, u'userDisplayName': u'John', u'createDate': u'1427860827', u'userID': 12857582, u'replyCount': 0, u'commentTitle': u'<br/>', u'status': u'approved', u'approveDate': u'1427860868', u'userTitle': u'NULL', u'editorsSelection': 0, u'statusID': 2, u'userURL': u'NULL', u'userLocation': u'Chicago', u'commentType': u'userReply', u'updateDate': u'1427860868', u'commentSequence': 14581040, u'commentBody': u"Yea, Martin, but what does the wife know. She doesn't like It's a Wonderful Life and doesn't even know Bert and Ernie were the cop and the cab driver. She just knows Bert and Ernie as muppets who used to baby sit for her.", u'recommendationCount': 1}, [...]
```

[Full JSON Data File](https://pastebin.com/qZ5hKB4j)

```
obj = json.loads(line)
```

I am unable to use `json.loads(mystring)` as it throws an error. What should I do?

Comment: How did you generated this JSON? Doesnt look like a valid [json](https://www.json.org) since a string (even unicode string) in JSON doesnt need the `u` at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Also, what error do you get?

Comment: @wendelbsilva I was thinking the same. This data i got from my mentor for my project. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

That link is not JSON but a python `dict`.

You can make it a valid JSON string using `dumps`:

`json_string = json.dumps(your_dict_variable)`

And then make it a dict (which it already is) using `loads`:

`json.loads(json_string)`

Comment: Thanks for the help @JacobiRR

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I am first reading the raw content from the text and then using the `literal_eval`to convert it to a python dictionary object.

**Demo**

```
import ast
import json
p = "PATH_TO/json_data.txt"
with open(p, "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()

data = ast.literal_eval(data)
print data['debug']
```

**Output**:

```
{u'version': 3.1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Rakesh